# Is there a way to have the bokeh HoverTool display a time series glyph instead of just text?

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, geopandas

This is more of an exploratory question so I don't have any code to share at this point, but my vision is to create an interactive map view of data using bokeh/geopandas and hopefully create/modify another custom HoverTool to display a time series chart with more granular hourly data for the polygon the HoverTool is over.

Does anyone know if this is possible and/or can lead me to an example where this has been done? Google and stackoverflow searches have come up empty so far. Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Bokeh [docs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#custom-tooltip) have an example showing how to create a "viz in a tooltip", to borrow Tableau terminology.

You can pre-generate time-series images specific to each polygon, include the URIs pointing to the images as a column in your data source and load them on hover.